# Magento 2: transactional e-mails not translated when triggered by code

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-email

I have created a custom module that automatically generates orders based on certain conditions. It is a subscription module.

When the orders get created via cronjob or command line (both point to the same code) everything works fine except that the resulting transactional e-mails are not being translated. They are supposed to be in german as they are when orders get created manuall via frontend.

How can I force the translation?

This is how the orders get created:

```
protected function _createOrder($data)
{
    /** @var $customer \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer */
    /** @var $quote \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote */
    /** @var $order \Magento\Sales\Model\Order */

    $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
    $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();

    if (!isset($data['customer_id']) || empty($data['customer_id'])) {
        return false;
    }

    try {
        $customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($data['customer_id']);
    } catch(\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        $this->_log($e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    $quote = $this->_quoteFactory->create();
    $quote->setStore($store);
    $quote->setCurrency();
    $quote->assignCustomer($customer);

    $product = $this->_product->load($data['product_id']);
    $product->setPrice($data['price']);
    $quote->addProduct(
        $product,
        intval($data['qty'])
    );

    $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData((array)$data['billing']);
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData((array)$data['shipping']);

    $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    $shippingAddress->collectShippingRates();
    $shippingAddress->setShippingMethod('tablerate_bestway');

    $quote
        ->setPaymentMethod('checkmo')
        ->setInventoryProcessed(false)
        ->setIsSubscription(true)
        ->save()
    ;

    $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'banktransfer']);
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();

    try {
        $order = $this->_quoteManagement->submit($quote);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $this->_log("Order creation failed: " . $e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    if (!$order) {
        return false;
    }

    return ($order->getEntityId() ? $order->getEntityId() : false);
}
```

Comment: change your mail delivery to async, then the emails will be sent with the correct locale.

Comment: There is no way to achieve this when sending directly?

Comment: probably, but I didn't find it and using async delivery makes more sense anyway...

Comment: Yay! Major Bummer. I switched to async delivery and the system immediately started sending out thousands of years old order and shipping mails. Lots of angry customers. So be careful before doing this switch.

Comment: Turns out the sudden sending of emails was due to a data migration (magento 1 -> magento 2) where the field "email_sent" was not properly set.

Comment: You live and learn...